# Concat several columns as new column in Rust Diesel 2.0.0

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

With Rust's Diesel (2.0.0), is there a way to concatenate several columns without raw SQL?

This works for PostgreSQL but it's not exactly elegant:

```rust
my_table::table
  .select((
    sql::<diesel::sql_types::Text>(&"CONCAT(col1, '-', col2, '-', col3) as id"),
    my_table::col1,
    my_table::col2,
    my_table::col3,
    my_table::col4,
  ))
  .filter(my_table::col1.eq("somevalue"))
  .get_result::<(String, String, i64, String, String)>(&mut conn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`sql_function!`](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/expression/functions/macro.sql_function.html) macro:

> Diesel only provides support for a very small number of SQL functions. This macro enables you to add additional functions from the SQL standard, as well as any custom functions your application might have.

```rust
sql_function! {
    fn concat(a: Text, b: Text, c: BigInt, d: Text, e: Text) -> Text;
}

my_table::table
    .select((
        concat(my_table::col1, "-", my_table::col2, "-", my_table::col3),
        my_table::col1,
        my_table::col2,
        my_table::col3,
        my_table::col4,
    ))
    ...
```

Comment: Of course! I've read the `sql_function` doc already but didn't think to use it in this instance. Thanks.

Comment: It's not necessary to define your own `concat` function, as diesel already provides a built-in function: https://docs.diesel.rs/2.1.x/diesel/expression_methods/trait.TextExpressionMethods.html#method.concat

(Using your own function also work, that comment just points out that this is not necessary)

Comment: @weiznich Is there a way to use `concat` for this? `col2` is an integer type and `.concat(my_table::col2)` complains that it's `Expression::SqlType` is not `Text`.

Comment: You would probably need to implement an explicit cast operator via `diesel::postfix_operator!` and use that to make the type conversions explicit.